# How to access $dispatch and other magic properties of Alpinejs from vanilla js file?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to build a toast notification component in Alpine.js. But I'm not getting to send notification from vanilla js files.

```
<div
    x-data="
        {
            notices: [],
            visible: [],
            add(notice) {
                notice.id = Date.now()
                this.notices.push(notice)
                this.fire(notice.id)
            },
            fire(id) {
                this.visible.push(this.notices.find(notice => notice.id == id))
                const timeShown = 10000 * this.visible.length
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.remove(id)
                }, timeShown)
            },
            remove(id) {
                const notice = this.visible.find(notice => notice.id == id)
                const index = this.visible.indexOf(notice)
                this.visible.splice(index, 1)
            },
        }
    "
    class="z-50 p-7 fixed inset-0 w-screen flex flex-col-reverse items-end justify-end pointer-events-none"
    @notice.window="add($event.detail)">
    <template x-for="notice of notices" :key="notice.id">
        <div
            x-show="visible.includes(notice)"
            x-transition:enter="transition ease-in duration-400"
            x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 translate-x-full"
            x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100"
            x-transition:leave="transition ease-out duration-500"
            x-transition:leave-start="transform translate-x-0 opacity-100"
            x-transition:leave-end="transform translate-x-full opacity-0"§
            @click="remove(notice.id)"
            class="rounded mb-4 p-3 w-full max-w-md text-green-800 shadow-lg cursor-pointer pointer-events-auto bg-green-200"
            x-text="notice.text">
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/nuno360/pen/WNGKmeL

From vanilla js file how I can send notices to this component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom event and dispatch it (assuming you're selecting an element of some sort) with `element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('notice', { detail: {}, bubbles: true }))`

Comment: Can you implement it on codepen? I tried with: `document.getElementById('notification').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('notices', { text: 'Success.' }));` but it's not works.

Comment: If you give me a codepen I'm happy to have a look your code should be closer to `document.getElementById('notification').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('notice', { detail: { text: 'Success.' }, bubbles: true }));` note the use of `notice` and a `detail` object

Comment: Thanks @Hugo for trying help. I updated codepen with your suggestion but it's not working: https://codepen.io/nuno360/pen/WNGKmeL

Comment: I've fixed it, by putting it directly in the JS file, the event dispatched before Alpine loads, if you make it happen on click of something it works, see https://codepen.io/hugodf/pen/dypqXGR

Comment: Since that codepen works, could you select this as the answer + upvote, thanks

Comment: That should work with `document.getElementById('notification').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('notice', { detail: { text: 'Success.' }, bubbles: true }));` as long as the fetch resolves after alpine initialises

Comment: Thanks Hugo for the reply. But why this `document.getElementById('notification').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('notice', { detail: { text: 'Success.' }, bubbles: true }));` don't work on codepen and you need put a trigger?

Comment: That's because the event was being dispatched before alpine was loaded.